# ngOptions statement to group by object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a JSON array:

```
"Fred": {
  "1": {
    "description": "Current Job"
   },
   "2": {
    "description": "Old Job"
   }
},
"George": {
      "1": {
        "description": "Another Current Job"
       },
       "2": {
        "description": "Another Old Job"
       }
   }
```

What I want the select field to populate is a list like this:

- Fred

  - Current Job
  - Old Job
- George

  - Another Current Job
  - Another old job

My current HTML is this:

```
<select id='job' name='job' ng=model='job' 
     ng-options='label.description as label.description group by tag for (tag, label) in data'>
    <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

But it returns

- Fred

  - (blank)
- George

  - (blank)

Comment: Your option value is empty. 
<option value=''></option>

Comment: That's the initial option. Its blank. The populated options look like: `<optgroup label='george'><option label='undefined' value='object:11'></option></optgroup>`

Comment: Is that really your array? The object in `Fred` is not closed properly. Please show your actual data and format.